# Listar valores no PHP com CheckboxListTitle e definir um id para cada checkbox listado

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou listando uns valores que são retornados de uma API em PHP. Nesta lista estou utilizando um `Checkbox` para cada informação.

Quando eu clico em qualquer `Checkbox`, todos itens da lista são selecionados. Como eu faço para pegar um item especifico?

Segue o código abaixo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class ListaCNPJ extends StatefulWidget {

  String cpf;
  String perfil;


  ListaCNPJ({this.cpf, this.perfil});

  @override
  _ListaCNPJState createState() => _ListaCNPJState();
}

class _ListaCNPJState extends State<ListaCNPJ> {

  bool _lista = false;
  //TextEditingController _controllerCNPJ = TextEditingController();

  Future getContactData(String cpf, String perfil) async {
    const URL = 'http://localhost/camera/api.php';
    var response = await http.get(
        URL + "?action=consultarCNPJ"
            "&cpf=$cpf"
            "&perfil=$perfil"
    );

    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Lista de CNPJs"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getContactData(widget.cpf, widget.perfil),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          print("resposta: "+snapshot.data.toString());
          if(snapshot.hasError){
            print(snapshot.error);
          }

          return snapshot.hasData ? Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    List list = snapshot.data;
                    return ListTile(
                        title: CheckboxListTile(
                            title: Text(list[index]['tb_empresa']),
                            subtitle: Text(list[index]['tb_cnpj']),
                            value: false, // _lista[index]["realizada"],
                            onChanged: (valor){
                              setState(() {
                                _lista = valor;
                              });


                            },
                        )
                    );
                  }
                )
              )
            ],
          ) :
          Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Esse artigo aqui pode te ajudar [Flutter descomplica - Checkbox](https://medium.com/flutter-comunidade-br/flutter-descomplica-lista-de-checkbox-1e0dca525cb)

Comment: Matheus fiz o que está no link que você me passou deu certo, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Todos os seus [Checkbox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html) estão com o mesmo comportamento pois o que vai ditar o estado deles é o valor que você coloca na propriedade `value: false,`.

Isto é, o que vai dizer se a Checkbox está marcada ou desmarcada é o valor que é colocado nesta propriedade. Se você usa o mesmo valor `_lista` para todas, todas vão ter o mesmo comportamento. O próprio nome da variável "lista" que você deu indica que quem escreveu talvez já tivesse pensado nisso.

Existem várias maneiras de resolver seu problema. Deixo aqui a mais simples que consegui pensar:

- Crie uma variável que irá agrupar uma lista de booleanos representando o estado de cada CheckBox:

```
List<bool> _lista;
```

- Quando receber suas informações, preencha sua lista com um valor inicial (por exemplo `false`) para cada CheckBox:

```
builder: (context, snapshot){
      if (snapshot.hasData){
          _lista = List<bool>.filled(snapshot.data.length, false);
      }
[...]
```

[Isso](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/List/List.filled.html) irá fazer uma lista na seguinte forma: `[false,false,false...]`.

- Utilize essa informação ao criar as Checkbox's:

```
value: _lista[index],
```

- E ao alterá-las também:

```
onChanged: (valor){
                       setState(() {
                           _lista[index] = valor;
                       });
                   },
```

Por último, o seu [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) está chamando essa função `getContactData` toda vez que a tela for redesenhada. Pela documentação oficial podemos ler:

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies.

Isto é, esse Future utilizado deve ser obtido antes, e armazenado na variável para ser utilizado no FutureBuilder:

```
Future retornoDaApi;
```

e no initState inicia-se a chamada a API e armazena-se o retorno nesta variável:

```
@override
initState() {
  super.initState();
  retornoDaApi = getContactData(widget.cpf, widget.perfil);
}
```

Para no FutureBuilder utilizar o Future dessa variável:

```
future:retornoDaApi,
```

Para maiores informações sugiro ler os links listados, que fazem parte da documentação oficial, sobre CheckBox e FutureBuilder.

Comment: tentei essa maneira mais obtive esse erro The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length, acredito que seja na atribuição do List segue abaixo            
 future: retornoDaApi,
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          _list = List<bool>.filled(snapshot.data.length, false);
         // print("resposta: "+snapshot.data.length.toString());
          if(snapshot.hasError){
            print(snapshot.error);
          }

Comment: @teste Ah sim. Precisa verificar se o snapshot tem dados antes. Voce já fez isso no código, algo do tipo ```if(snapshot.hasData) { _list = List<bool>.filled(snapshot.data.length, false);}```. Vou editar a resposta para incluir isso.

Comment: o erro Sumiu porém o checkbox não esta marcando, eu printei a variavel _lista[index] está retornando true